# jquery .find() in IE 8 - no matches

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

i developed a small slide show for a small project and it worked fine. In Google Chrome, Opera, Friefox and IE 9. But in IE 8 and IE 7 it doesnt work.

I detected the problem - the problem is, that IE 7 and IE 8 dont find the elements in dom.

Here it is:

```
window.alert(thisWrapper.find('img').length); // returns 4 in all browser - in IE7 and IE8 it returns 0
thisWrapper.find('img').each(function(){
// do something with it

    });
```

i started the function in the typical dom-check:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ /* start sldier here */});
```

Any solution why it doenst work like in the other browsers ?

edit:

thisWrapper contains something like this: jQuery('#slider')

Comment: jQuery('#slider'). And in <div id="slider"></div> are a few <img /> tags with the right sourca to the images.

Comment: You will most likely be able to blame this on invalid HTML, which is been handled differently by different browsers; IE will be *fixing* it by bringing the elements *out* of where you think they are. Validate your HTML on http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks very much! In response to your comment i noticed that my template is HTML5 - so i just added the html5shiv by google and it works fine! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> In response to your comment i noticed that my template is HTML5 - so i just added the html5shiv by google and it works fine!